# Older and Odor - Pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I know the only difference between the two is that "Older" has an "L" sound. But I want to know if that "L" is obvious to native speaker? Or it could be easily mistaken.

Comment: I don't think I've ever misheard one as the other. But it seems unlikely that they'd ever fit into the same context, so that may prevent confusion.

Comment: If someone has a cold, it could possibly be hard to detect the "L", but otherwise, to my native ears, I hear the "L".

Comment: I think the /l/ causes the first syllable to be lengthened. So even if you don't actually hear the /l/ sound, the word sounds more like "ooodor".

Comment: What accent would the speaker have in order to pronounce the two words similar ? I didn't yet hear such an accent.

Comment: The /l/ is more prominent to an American native speaker than the /d/, and most of us would be satisfied saying or hearing /'olər/, as in /ʃiz'olərṇmi/ _She's older than me_.

Comment: I almost never enunciate the /l/ - at most there's a /w/, but that's the same in both. Nevertheless, the first vowel component in each diphthong is completely different to me, so I could never get them mixed up.

Comment: For this US English speaker the tip of my tongue arches up and touches the roof of my mouth behind my upper teeth for the L sound of "older".  When pronouncing "odor" the tongue touches farther back and not until the D is voiced.  The D is produced with approximately the same tongue position in both cases, but the L sound is reasonably distinct and separate from the D.

Comment: Do you have any difference in how you pronounce the word *owed* versus *old*?

Comment: @jxh - The difference between "owed" and "old" is quite small -- I can sense it in my mouth, but barely, and one would probably need a spectrum analyzer to pick out an audible difference.  (Of course, if I were making a specific effort to speak distinctly the difference would be more substantial.  This would be mainly achieved by prolonging the L sound.)

Comment: @HotLicks: Among my childhood friends in the Midwest US, we would never mix up "He's old money." from "He's owed money." among ourselves. Are you saying someone who speaks with your same dialect would not be able to pick up the difference for you?

Comment: @jxh - It would certainly depend on how attuned someone was to the precise dialect, and how rapidly I was speaking.  I can at least understand how they might be confused.

Comment: @HotLicks: I can understand how a non-native speaker might have difficulty if their native language lacked a distinctive 'L' sound.

Answer (score 5):

In my (UK) accent, the vowels are completely different: /ɒldə/ versus /əʊdə/. In an Essex accent, the l will be vocalised to /ʊ/, giving /ɒʊdə/, but the vowel (diphthong) will still be quite different.

Answer (score 3):

In AmE, in my experience at least, the pronunciations of the two are quite different. The `L` is pronounced in *older*.

Answer (score 1):

In some British dialects "older" is in fact pronounced as /ouder/ without l.
Nevertheless the word classes of the two words are different and the structures in which they are used are totally different. So the two words, even if pronounced alike, will hardly lead to misunderstandings.